# Nested ssh run commands on 2nd server

Tags: bash, ssh

I can only get to hostB from hostA, and I want to run commands on hostB.

```
ssh -t $hostA ssh -t $hostB "

   echo 'Hello World!'

   echo 'Test!'

"
```

At the moment, this will connect to hostA then hostB and the script will pause. As soon as i type exit (from hostB) I return to hostA, the 2 echo commands are printed and then automatically exits from hostA.

How can I run commands on hostB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing code as using here document and `sshpass` can do the trick

```
ssh -T user@$hostA <<EOA
sshpass -p password ssh  -T user@$hostB <<EOB
echo hello 
EOB
EOA
```

Comment: Before hostA prompts for password I get `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` And then I type in password for hostA... Then no password prompt is given for hostB and I immediately get `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
`

Comment: @j.con get rid of the `-t` option. i am not sure but it may work

Comment: -t removed on both ssh lines... same effect

Comment: @j.con sorry but isnt it `-T` instead of `-t`??

Comment: @j.con, the pseudo-terminal message is unrelated and unimportant to the authentication failure, except inasmuch as not having a TTY prevents a second, inner password prompt. Use an SSH agent with forwarding in the outer connection (`ssh -A`), and you'll work around the latter.

Comment: `-t` forces pseudo-tty... `-T` disables pseudo-tty... `-t` has no effect, and `-T` removes the `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` error but then it still skips password prompt for hostB

Comment: @j.con, ...but having a password prompt at all is silly when you could use agent authentication and present the same authentication token to both servers.

Comment: @j.con i have edite the answer with working code. Hope it works now

Comment: @j.con i tried without sshpass but got `permission denied`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-J` option.

```
ssh $hostB -J $hostA "..."
```