# SSH to nested servers

Tags: shell, ssh

I have a Bash script `test.sh` in my local machine.

I need to run the script to my AWS instances but in order to log in to the AWS servers(instance), I need to login to the respective bastion server and then log in to the instance and run the script.

```
Local >> bastion server >> AWS instances(run test.sh)
```

The output of the script executed on AWS instances should be printed on the local machine's terminals.

I have 3 bastion server and 3 AWS instances where I need to run the same script and get the output.

```
bastion1 >> AWS inst_1

bastion2 >> AWS inst_2

bastion3 >> AWS inst_3
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested ssh run commands on 2nd server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866082/nested-ssh-run-commands-on-2nd-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-J` option to specify the bastion:

```
ssh -J bastion1 aws_inst1 "test.sh"
ssh -J bastion2 aws_inst2 "test.sh"
ssh -J bastion3 aws_inst3 "test.sh"
```

However, as the mapping from bastion to AWS instanced is fixed, I would add these to your ssh config file. (`~/.ssh/config`)

```
Host aws1
    Hostname  aws_inst1
    ProxyJump bastion1

Host aws2
    Hostname  aws_inst2
    ProxyJump bastion2

Host aws3
    Hostname  aws_inst3
    ProxyJump bastion3
```

With this in place, you can simply write

```
ssh aws1 test.sh
ssh aws2 test.sh
ssh aws3 test.sh
```